# I ordered 'print at home' tickets at Greyhound, but cannot take print out before the bus time

Tags: usa, tickets, buses, greyhound

I ordered 'print at home' tickets from Greyhound (Binghamton to NYC), but I do not have printer at home. My university library, where I usually print, closed earlier than expected due to some reasons. What should I do now? Should I talk to the people at the terminal ticket counter and explain my situation or do I need to buy a new ticket? Has anyone been in this situation before?

Comment: Copy the tickets to a USB stick, or burn to a CD/DVD, and go to Office Max, Office Depot, FedEx Kinkos, or some similar place. They should be able to print it for you.

Comment: I hated this about Greyhound. Their BoltBus subsidiary allows you to board with just the ticket on your phone screen; why can't Greyhound buses?

Comment: Is the local public library an option? They usually have printing at a reasonable cost, and hopefully you can get set up with a card using your school address.

Comment: FedEx Office are common and a really good way to print. The copier has an email address you can forward the document and place to swipe your credit card to pay the few cents.

Comment: I tried buying a Greyhound ticket while traveling with no access to a printer.  The checkout screen only had a "print at home" option and the "will call" option was disabled.  The motel front desk refused to print anything out for me.  I ended up booking an Amtrak bus ticket - they accept e-tickets on your phone.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you can, try an internet cafe - they usually have printers available.  Alternatively, another student? If you have time, even walking into a nearby office and explaining yourself may get you a pity print ;)

Alternatively, go to the Greyhound terminal early and ask (or better call their help line).  But do ask first before buying another ticket - you lose nothing by asking, and they may solve it for you easily.  However, note that [on their website, it says](http://www.greyhound.com/en/help/printathome.aspx):

> "It is solely the passenger’s responsibility to print tickets prior to
>   travel. The terminal will not be able to print your ticket"

so you'd be lucky if you got a generous counter agent willing to do so.

What they suggest doing online is:

> If you are unable to print ticket after following all the instructions
>   above, please contact our Web Support. An agent may be reached via
>   email at Web.Support@greyhound.com or by phone at 1-800-268-9000.
>
> When calling, inform the agent of the following:
>
> - Your Print at Home Ticket could not be retrieved from Greyhound.com
> - First and last name of the passenger traveling
> - Departure city
> - Date of departure
>
> Please note that for security reasons, other information may be
>   required before travel details are released. If you are unable to
>   contact the Customer Service Center or are within one hour of
>   scheduled departure, it is recommended that you purchase a new ticket
>   at the counter and submit the email ticket for refund through the
>   Customer Service Center at a later date.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just take it to a neighbour, friend, colleague who lives near you (surely someone you know must have a printer) and let them print it for you !